# Alloy Framework - When to use Window, Controller and View

Tags: android, android-layout, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have simple android app mockup with home screen.
Homescreen contains 3 options: start game, settings and leaderboards.
I am not sure, what alloy components should I use for screens like settings etc.

Should I use different controllers for home, menu, settings etc? Or should they be just different Views in the same window? I can't find information about good practice for titanium app design.

Answer (score 0):

Well we tend to use a separate controller for each separate piece of functionality.  If each controller would be displayed in a separate window then in this case I'd have 6 files:

```
/controllers/startgame.js
/views/startgame.xml
/styles/startgame.tss

/controllers/settings.js
/views/settings.xml
/style/settings.tss

/controllers/leaderboards.js
/views/leaderboards.xml
/style/leaderboards.tss
```

just use "alloy generate controller" on the CLI to generate them quickly.

Comment: What solution do you use to change visible screen? Is the 
Alloy.createController('controller_name').getView().open(); a proper way to do this?

Comment: We usually use a variable then to variable.open(); just for readability but yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look this framework:  [ChariTi-CB](https://github.com/CBMVC/ChariTi-CB)

Actually, I will prefer use one window and include all screens, and use the view for each screen, in this way, if you want to control the window style (like the orientationModes), you just can easy to control it in the app. The above framework is use this design pattern.